# What's the point of Harry's flashbacks in "Birdland" (S03 Episode 06)

Tags: analysis, bosch

Throughout the entire episode "Birdland" (6th episode of the third season of [Bosch](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3502248/)) we're shown a flashback from Harry's childhood, eating cranberry cobbler at a restaurant on Thanksgiving. In present day it's also Thanksgiving.

But why are we seeing this specific memory? Besides the obvious Thanksgiving connection is there any other meaning to it, any other connection to what Harry is going through in the present?

Comment: I really don't remember that season all too well anymore. But there is one season that generally goes a lot more into Bosch's past, as well as his mother's death and his time in the orphanage. If that's the same season, this flashback might just be a looser part of that general childhood theming. Intertesting question, though.

Comment: I'm currently watching season 3 and indeed it goes a lot into his past. But this flashback intrigued me, because it's sprinkled throughout the episode and it doesn't seem connected to anything, but I wonder if the conclusion of the flashback has any meaning to his present situation, more than just "I remember that Thanksgiving".